# Android: onKeyDown only gets called once with options menu button

Tags: android, menu, onkeydown

I am using an ActivityGroup that overrides onKeyDown which is needed to handle the Back button. If you press the menu button while on the first activtiy, the option menu does get created. If I then navigate to a 2nd activity within this activity group and press the menu button again, the menu appears as is expected. But when I return back to the first activity, the menu button never works again. The menu never gets called. If you then navigate back to the 2nd activity and press the menu button it works. Now if you navigate from that activity to a 3rd activity, the menu button will work there but not on the 1st or 2nd activity. This problem shows up only on OS 2.3. It works as is expected on OS 2.2. Somehow, it seems each activity takes over the menu handler and doesn't release it, even though I destroy the activity when returning back to the previous one. There is no onKeyDown handler or menu creation in any activity other than the first one. Is this a bug in 2.2 or just from the manufacturer (Huawei)?

Comment: Seems like a bug, or at least weird. Have you tried re-attaching the listeners?

Comment: How do you reattach a listener? I am only using onCreateOptionsMenu and onKeyDown. How do you re-attach stuff like that since it's just being overridden?

Comment: Maybe bad choice of words. I just meant something like "setBlaListener" in the onResume/Create/Something else

Comment: `ActivityGroup` has been deprecated for over a year. `onBackPressed()` has been the proper way to handle the BACK button for 2.5 years.